# Error with Smartface device emulator

Tags: smartface.io

Does anyone know how to fix the error with Smartface app studios where in device emulator it tells me the app is not download when i have it on my iphone?

Please respond with any sugestions

Comment: Can you provide more information? The question is slightly unclear and/or hard to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

See this answer: [Smartface 4.3.0. Emulator on iOS 8.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30451668/smartface-4-3-0-emulator-on-ios-8-3)

There is an issue on iOS 8.3. On this version the iOS emulator is not working anymore. In the next version of Smartface the iOS emulator will be available only for paid accounts.