# Smartface 4.3.0. Emulator on iOS 8.3

Tags: smartface.io

I have iOS 8.3 on my iPhone, so the emulator is not working.
I get this message: "Keep calm ;) You need to download Smartface in action from app store and then please try again."
I have an individual license, please advise.
Is this going to be fixed in Smartface 4.4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you heard about the restrictions in iOS 8.3.

Yes, for licenced users iOS emulator will be available again with the next release, which will be ready soon.

If you have a Mac, you can download the emulator project from the link below : https://github.com/smartface/iOS-Emulator
And you can compile it by yourself until the new release of Smartface4.4 is ready.

By the way, Android emulator was always and will always be available to use for all users including community users.

Comment: OK. Thanks! I have a Mac and tried to compile the iOS-Emulator from github, but i get a lot of errors and the project doesn't compile. Anyway in order to use the the compiled emulator on an actual device I need an Apple payed developer account. So the only way to test on a iOS device is to wait for Smartface 4.4

Comment: Any news when the new Smartface 4.4 will be released?