# Smartface not running , my iphone has an emulator

Tags: smartface.io

I use
smartface 4.3 & 
itunes 12, 
but when I press device emulator button in the smartface editor I get:

> Keep calm ;) You need to download “Smartface in Action” from App Store and then please try again.

How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Do you use an iPhone?
Do you have iOS 8.3 on your iPhone?

See this answer: [Smartface 4.3.0. Emulator on iOS 8.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30451668/smartface-4-3-0-emulator-on-ios-8-3)

There is an issue on iOS 8.3. On this version the iOS emulator is not working anymore. In the next version of Smartface the iOS emulator will be available only for paid accounts.